# React move an image over another every few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a background image for my component. I want 1 more image which is 48 * 48 (small image)
to move on it from left to right and top randomly. Here is the code of my background image -

```
const sectionStyle = {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center'
};
```

Then the render of the compoent has div which uses sectionStyle.

How do I get this small image moving on the background image randomly every few seconds?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use use absolute positioning and define state for position of your image. Then you can change positions with setInterval.

It might not be the best way possible but it will get the work done. Here's an example implementation. (I've taken random values for the ease of understanding) -

```
const styles = {
  mainContainerStyle: {
    margin: '50px',
    background: 'yellow',
    padding: '20px',
    height: '600px',
  },

  backgroundContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    background: `url('YOUR_BACKGROUND_IMAGE')`,
    width: '400px',
    height: '400px',
  },

  imageStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 45,
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
}

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
    }
  }

  randomMovement = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      left: prevState.left + 30 * Math.random(),
      top: prevState.top + 30 * Math.random(),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.mainContainerStyle}>
        <div style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
          <img
            src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL"
            style={{
              ...styles.imageStyle,
              top: this.state.top,
              left: this.state.left,
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startMovement = setInterval(this.randomMovement, 3000);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.